# Data loss when adding a record to the database

Tags: java, spring-boot, java.util.concurrent

Help me understand the work with the database, on the 3-5 iteration, data is incorrectly written to the database in the lemma table, the site is correctly recorded, the page is also, but when lemma then records in the database are different.

I am writing a search engine, the program works as follows, a rest request is sent, and sites are parsed in parallel, collecting page, and lemma, the work is performed in parallel, each site in its own thread, and each site additionally using forkjoin parses pages and immediately saves lemma in the database, but at the end of the program the number of lemma is different. I found out that in the insertLemmasToTable method, the text variable has different values, for this I wrote code for testing, where I found out that the text variable has different values. The extractWordsFromUrl method collects all words from html, and it is here that different data on the 3-5 restart of the program.

text
Total Word Count: 77829
Total Word Count: 77829
Total Word Count: 77855

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I installed synchronized blocks

Comment: Please **do not** post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: It’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce the issue. See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).